# Clustering with DBSCAN: How to train a model if you dont set the number of clusters in advance?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am using  built-in dataset iris from sklearn for clustering. In KMeans I set the number of clusters in advance but it is not true for DBSCAN. How to train a model if you dont set the number of clusters in advance?

I tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#%matplotib inline

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN,MeanShift
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split,KFold,cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score,confusion_matrix

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps=0.3,min_samples=10)

dbscan.fit(X,y)
```

I have got stuck on it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DBSCAN is a clustering algorithm and, as such, it does not employ the labels `y`. It is true that you can use its `fit` method as `.fit(X, y)` but, according to the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.fit):

> **y: Ignored**
>
> Not used, present here for API consistency by convention.

The other characteristic of DBSCAN is that, in contrast to algorithms such as KMeans, it does not take the number of clusters as an input; instead, it also **estimates** their number by itself.

Having clarified that, let's adapt the [documentation demo](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_dbscan.html) with the iris data:

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, labels_true = load_iris(return_X_y=True) 
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)

# Compute DBSCAN
db = DBSCAN(eps=0.5,min_samples=5) # default parameter values
db.fit(X)
core_samples_mask = np.zeros_like(db.labels_, dtype=bool)
core_samples_mask[db.core_sample_indices_] = True
labels = db.labels_

# Number of clusters in labels, ignoring noise if present.
n_clusters_ = len(set(labels)) - (1 if -1 in labels else 0)
n_noise_ = list(labels).count(-1)

print('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
print('Estimated number of noise points: %d' % n_noise_)
print("Homogeneity: %0.3f" % metrics.homogeneity_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Completeness: %0.3f" % metrics.completeness_score(labels_true, labels))
print("V-measure: %0.3f" % metrics.v_measure_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Rand Index: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Adjusted Mutual Information: %0.3f"
      % metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score(labels_true, labels))
print("Silhouette Coefficient: %0.3f"
      % metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels))
```

Result:

```
Estimated number of clusters: 2
Estimated number of noise points: 17
Homogeneity: 0.560
Completeness: 0.657
V-measure: 0.604
Adjusted Rand Index: 0.521
Adjusted Mutual Information: 0.599
Silhouette Coefficient: 0.486
```

Let's plot them:

```
# Plot result
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Black removed and is used for noise instead.
unique_labels = set(labels)
colors = [plt.cm.Spectral(each)
          for each in np.linspace(0, 1, len(unique_labels))]
for k, col in zip(unique_labels, colors):
    if k == -1:
        # Black used for noise.
        col = [0, 0, 0, 1]

    class_member_mask = (labels == k)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=14)

    xy = X[class_member_mask & ~core_samples_mask]
    plt.plot(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1], 'o', markerfacecolor=tuple(col),
             markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)

plt.title('Estimated number of clusters: %d' % n_clusters_)
plt.show()
```

[image]

That's it.

As with all clustering algorithms, here the usual notions of supervised learning, like train/test split, predict with unseen data, cross validation etc **do not hold**. Such unsupervised methods may be useful in an initial exploratory data analysis (EDA), in order to give us a general idea about our data - but, as you may have noticed already, it is not necessary that the findings from such analysis are useful for supervised problems: here, despite the existence of 3 labels in our iris dataset, the algorithm uncovered only 2 clusters.

... which may of course change, depending on the model parameters. Experiment...

Comment: Is it possible to use 3 clusters with DSCAN?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Again: it is not up to you to "ask" for any specific number of clusters; the algorithm itself will estimate that number from the data, which can change depending on the parameters used for fitting DBSCAN. Here, with these settings, it found 2 clusters; in the documentation demo (linked above) it finds 3.

Answer (score 3):

One of the advantages of DBSCAN on Kmeans is that you do not need to specify the number of clusters as a hyperparameter. The most important parameter in DBSCAN is the epsilon that has a direct effect on the final number of clusters.

Comment: How to run the DBSCAN? Could you continue my trial?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Your code is correct. After clustering, you can find clusters using `dbscan.labels_`.

Comment: I am not sure If I have to do dbscan.fit(X,y) or dbscan.fit(X). How can I use fit.predict?

Comment: @LaurindaSouza Opps! You do not need to predict! it's a clustering task! Hence, both `dbscan.fit(X,y)` and `dbscan.fit(X)` are correct (`y` will be ignored!). And as I said, you can find the cluster index of `X` by `dbscan.labels_`.

Comment: How to test and train the model? I did not use train_test_split or KFold...

Comment: @LaurindaSouza, please! It's an unsupervised task! You don't need to `train` the model. Also, you can't test it like supervised learning. You can measure some renowned metrics such as silhouette distance. You need to read more text about machine learning.